# Right contour for integrating goniometric function with the $x^n$ as an argument

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

How would you integrate:

$\int_0^\infty \sin (x^n) \,dx$ $\;$for $n \gt 1$

- I mean the result is via gamma function and there exists a formula for that gamma function but I struggled with the rooting of the complex number
- Can I integrate this function using some convenient contour (complex)? Different way that using gamma function?No Idea how it would look like

The solution according to my textbook is $\  \frac {1}{n} \Gamma (\frac {1}{n}) \sin (\frac {\pi}{2n})$

My attempt:

$\int_0^\infty \sin (x^n) \,dx = \int_0^\infty \sin (z^n) \,dz = Im \int_0^\infty \exp (iz^n) \,dz$

- where $z$ is a complex number, $x$ is real and I don't know the Laplace transform so please lets avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x^n)dx=-\Im\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^n}dx$$
$$=-\Im \lim_{a\to0}\int_0^\infty e^{-(a+i)x^n}dx=-\Im\lim_{a\to0}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}e^{-(a+i)x}dx$$
$$=-\Im\lim_{a\to 0}\Gamma(\frac{1}{n})\frac{(a+i)^{-\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{n})}{n}(-\Im(e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2n}}))=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{n})}{n}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n}).$$

No need to use countour integration all you need is the definition of the gamma function and Euler's Formula.

Comment: I can let x being x? No need to write it as a real part of complex number z? I am confused what needs to be complex and what dont. So x is real, right?

Comment: Yup since you are integrating over real values, you can use u-substitution I just forgoed that step since the integration limits and overall answer is the same.

Comment: Yeah and because the x is on the positive axis i can root it, right. Thank you.

Comment: Change of variables $u=x^n$

Comment: Dumb question, u is still real, right?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty \cos(x^n)+i\sin(x^n)dx\right)=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty e^{ix^n}dx\right)$$
Now you could try and use a summation to solve this:
$$I=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{(ix^n)^r}{r!}dx\right)=\Im\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{i^r}{r!}\int_0^\infty x^{nr}dx\right)$$
$$=\Im\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{i^r}{r!}\left[\frac{x^{nr+1}}{nr}\right]_0^\infty\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Im\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{i^rx^{nr+1}}{nr.r!}\right),$$
although I don't think this appears to lead anywhere.

coming back to a previous step:
$$I(n)=\Im\left(\int_0^\infty e^{ix^n}dx\right)$$
$$I'(n)=\Im\left(i\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}e^{ie^{n\ln(x)}}dx\right)$$
$$=\Im\left(i\int_0^\infty ix^n\ln(x)e^{ix^n}dx\right)
=-\Im\left(\int_0^\infty x^n\ln(x)e^{ix^n}dx\right)$$
this may lead somewhere